# Converting Json Table

Tags: powershell

I am trying to convert below Json table to Json array object, below json failed because of there is single nested json object, but its working when there are multiple objects in nested json

```
       [
          {
            "name": "PrimaryResult",
            "columns": [
              {
                "name": "Computer",
                "type": "string"
              },
              {
                "name": "LastHeartbeat",
                "type": "datetime"
              }
            ],
            "rows": [
              [
                "xxxxxxx.dev.org",
                "2022-01-19T04:49:48.937Z"
              ]
            ]
          }
        ]
```

Expected output is as below

```
                          [
                           {
                            "Computer":  xxxxxxx.dev.org",
                            "LastHeartbeat":  "2022-01-19T04:49:48.937Z"
                           }
                         ]
```

I have tried with the below Json script it works when there are multiple objects in array

```
         [
          {
            "name": "PrimaryResult",
            "columns": [
              {
                "name": "Computer",
                "type": "string"
              },
              {
                "name": "LastHeartbeat",
                "type": "datetime"
              }
            ],
            "rows": [
              [
                "zzzzz.test.org",
                "2022-01-04T09:06:45.44Z"
              ],
              [
                "yyyy.dev.org",
                "2022-01-04T09:06:30.233Z"
              ],
              [
                "xxxx.prod.org",
                "2022-01-04T09:06:08.893Z"
              ],
              [
                "xxxx.dev.org",
                "2022-01-04T09:06:04.667Z"
              ]
            ]
          }
        ]
```

```
I have tried with below powershell script
=============================================
$TriggerMetadata = Get-Content .\test4.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$affected_resources = $TriggerMetadata.tables
$resources = 
    ForEach($Row in $affected_resources.rows)
    {
        $TmpHash = [Ordered]@{}
        For($i = 0; $i -lt $Row.Length; $i++ )
        {
            $TmpHash.Add($affected_resources.columns.name[$i], $Row[$i] )
        }
        [PSCustomObject]$TmpHash
    }
$body = $resources | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
$Body
```

Getting below error

```
Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key"
At line:22 char:13
+             $TmpHash.Add($affected_resources.columns.name[$i], $Row[$ ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException
```

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is or how to reproduce it - which exact array are you talking about? `.tables.rows`? Does it break if `rows` contains a single nested array?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks for checking, yes its break only one single nested array, script need to handle 1 or more nested array, but my script handles more than 1 array and it breaks when single nested array

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Apologies need to remove   "tables":  at the start

Comment: Note that convertto-json, which you are not showing, has a default depth of 2.  I usually make it -depth 100.  Using $affected_resources as both the input and output of the foreach loop is probably not a good idea.  You could put back tables and put curly braces around the whole thing `{ }` .

Comment: @js2010 Made the changes and updated the script also i can not add braces around it since i am receiving like from azure alert as mentioned above

Comment: I do have a very similar answer for a very similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70653774/15339544 is that not working?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon that script works fine when there is single object in nested array and it fails when there are more than one object in nested array, as per my requirement one script need to handle both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell 'unravels' arrays when there is only one element in it.
In this case that produces the error you encounter you can fix by using the [, unary comma operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-6#comma-operator-) which will wrap the single element of the input array into another single element array.

When PowerShell unwraps that, the result is the original array of row values from the json file

Assuming you have the JSON converted in a variable `$json`:

```
$headers = $json.columns.name
# if there is only one 'rows 'element, wrap it in an array by prefixing with comma
if ($json.rows[0] -is [array]) { $rows = $json.rows } else { $rows = ,$json.rows }
$resources = $rows | ForEach-Object {
    $hash = [ordered]@{}
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $headers.Count; $i++) {
        $hash[$headers[$i]] = $_[$i]
    }
    [PsCustomObject]$hash
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "Computer":  "zzzzz.test.org",
    "LastHeartbeat":  "2022-01-04T09:06:45.44Z"
}
```

If you really do need the square brackets around that, you can do the test as before and enclose the result in '[..]'

```
if ($json.rows[0] -is [array]) { 
    $body = $resources | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
}
else {
    $body = "[ {0} ]" -f ($resources | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)
}
```

Output:

```
[ {
    "Computer":  "zzzzz.test.org",
    "LastHeartbeat":  "2022-01-04T09:06:45.44Z"
} ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help mate, its working both single and multiple objects in array